# JSON Encode and Decode with objects in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, json.net

I have the following code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Module Module1

Structure JSONList
    Dim Name, Email As String
    Dim Age As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()
    Dim Data(1) As JSONList

    Data(0).Name = "Josh"
    Data(0).Age = 17
    Data(0).Email = "me@mail.co.uk"
    Data(1).Name = "Greg"
    Data(1).Age = 17
    Data(1).Email = "greg@hotmail.co.uk"

    Dim JSONEncode As String
    JSONEncode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data)
    Console.WriteLine(JSONEncode)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim JSONDecode() As JSONList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONEncode)
    Console.WriteLine(JSONDecode(0).Name)

    Console.ReadKey()


End Sub

End Module
```

The first encoding part of the script is used to store the encoded string to a database, the output is:

```
[{"Name":"Josh","Email":"me@mail.co.uk","Age":17},{"Name":"Greg","Email":"greg@hotmail.co.uk","Age":17}]
```

Now when I try to decode this JSON string, I get an error `Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'JSONList[]'.`

I need the data to be encoded in the JSON format so that I can use it in my website that uses PHP to decode it. I am using Visual Basic 2010 along with JSON.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` deserialises into an object of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` which .net cannot automatically convert to an array of `JSONList`. A little bit of conversion is required:

```
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray =
                                        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONEncode)

Dim JSONDecode() As JSONList = (
                                 From j In jsonObject
                                 Select New JSONList() With {.Age = j("Age"),
                                                             .Email = j("Email"),
                                                             .Name = j("Name")}
                               ).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian said, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` will deserialize to `JArray`, which .Net cannot automatically convert into an array of your `JSONList` structure.  However, you don't need to do manual conversion; you simply need to use the overload of `DeserializeObject` which accepts a type parameter.  This will allow Json.Net to deserialize directly to your type without needing any special conversion code.

```
Dim JSONDecode() As JSONList = _
                 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSONList())(JSONEncode)
```